# VBA IE Dropdown Select

Tags: excel, vba

Team, I'm currently working on a IE Navigation using VBA Excel. Having issue with drop down selection, I would like to select the value "3" (question_12213765) but my code is not working. Little help is much appreciated.

Current Code:

```
Set doc = ie.document
   
doc.getElementsByName("question_12213760")(0).Value = Sheets("Controls").Range("D4").Value 'adding file name

doc.getElementsByName("question_12213761")(0).Value = Sheets("Controls").Range("D5").Value 'adding analyst name

doc.getElementsByName("question_12213762")(0).Value = Sheets("Controls").Range("D6").Value 'adding supervisor

doc.getElementsByName("question_12213763")(0).Value = Sheets("Controls").Range("D7").Value 'adding manager

doc.getElementsByName("question_12213764")(0).Value = Sheets("Controls").Range("D8").Value 'adding date

'adding value
doc.getElementsByID("question_12213765_response")(0).Value = "76011183" 'adding Protection value
```

[image]

Comment: "I'm currently working on a IE Navigation using VBA Excel." - what do you mean by "IE navigation"? If you mean Internet Explorer, **OH DEAR GOD WHY??!** - IE has been completely dead since 2015, Microsoft even held a funeral for it! http://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/03/04/ie6.funeral/index.html - what possible reason could you have for using IE? Also, your VBA code shows you using MSHTML, that's not _exactly_ the same thing as IE...

Comment: Yes that's the only one working with Excel (as far as I know). And lucky some of my codes are working the way I want them except for dropdown thing.

Comment: You don't have `doc.getElementsByName("question_12213765")` anywhere in your posted code, so it's no-wonder it's not doing anything for that `<select>` element.